# How to tell which Signing Identity used to sign a provisioning profile in the Developer Portal

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm looking at my provisioning profile in the Apple developer portal and see three certificates with the same name, but no additional details.  It shows which one was used to sign the profile.

[image]

How can I tell which one was used if they have the same name but are slightly different. When viewed through Visual Studio or XCode, each certificate has a title but also an alpha numeric string

Comment: Not suggesting using the same name with provisioning profile.It represent a team name file name. From the expiration date, they are all available.If want to know their detail info , maybe should look at apple develop center's configure.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean that you should in apple develop acount about certificate info to see which be used.